# Программа на python при помощи pyside2

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyside2, qt-designer

Как сделать так, чтобы открывалось столько окон, сколько было нажатий на кнопку "`next`", можете прописать решение в функции `BPnextTask()`?

Я добился того, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "`pushButton_13`" открывалось случайное окно, все варианты которого представлены в списках `tasks`(названия окон) и `uis`(интерфейсы одноименных окон).

Открывшееся окно имеет кнопку "`next`", при нажатии на которую должно открываться случайное окно из того же списка.

Я пробовал скопировать код и вставить его в функцию "`BPnextTask`", предварительно поменяв названия переменных, но проблема заключается в том, что после открытия второго окна кнопка "`next`" не работает. Мне же нужно сделать так, чтобы у каждого последующего открытого окна работала эта кнопка, вызывая случайное окно по принципу ниже представленного кода. Заранее спасибо!

```
def BPall():
    global tasks
    tasks = ['t28', 't210', 't216', 
    't82', 't810', 't816', 
    't102', 't108', 't1016', 
    't162', 't128', 't1610']

    uis = [Ui_t28(), Ui_t210(), Ui_t216(), 
    Ui_t82(), Ui_t810(), Ui_t816(), 
    Ui_t102(), Ui_t108(), Ui_t1016(), 
    Ui_t162(), Ui_t168(), Ui_t1610()]

    task = random.randint(0, 11)

    tasks[task] = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = uis[task]
    ui.setupUi(tasks[task])
    training.close()
    tasks[task].show()

    #transport to main from mixed task
    def BPhomeFromMixed():
        tasks[task].close()
        main.show()

    ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(BPhomeFromMixed)
    
    def BPnextTask():
        pass
    
    ui.next.clicked.connect(BPnextTask)

ui.pushButton_13.clicked.connect(BPall)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Достаточно, или еще нужно пояснить некоторые моменты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Минимально-воспроизводимый пример***, это когда скопировал его, запустил
и получил какой-то результат. Учтите пожалуйста это.

Не знаю, правильно ли я вас понял, но предлагаю проверить следующее:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_t28(object):
    def setupUi(self, t28):
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(t28)
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Ui_t28", t28)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.control_bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Next", t28)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.control_bt)


class Ui_t210(object):
    def setupUi(self, t210):
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(t210)
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Ui_t210", t210)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.control_bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Next", t210)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.control_bt)


class Ui_t216(object):
    def setupUi(self, t216):
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(t216)
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Ui_t216", t216)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.control_bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Next", t216)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.control_bt)


class Ui_t82(object):
    def setupUi(self, t82):
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(t82)
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Ui_t82", t82)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.control_bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Next", t82)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.control_bt)

        
class Ui_t810(object):
    def setupUi(self, t810):
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(t810)
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Ui_t810", t810)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.control_bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Next", t810)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.control_bt)


class Ui_t816(object):
    def setupUi(self, t816):
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(t816)
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Ui_t816", t816)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.control_bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Next", t816)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.control_bt)

        
class Ui_t102(object):
    def setupUi(self, t102):
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(t102)
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Ui_t102", t102)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.control_bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Next", t102)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.control_bt)


class Ui_t108(object):
    def setupUi(self, t108):
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(t108)
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Ui_t108", t108)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.control_bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Next", t108)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.control_bt)

        
class Ui_t1016(object):
    def setupUi(self, t1016):
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(t1016)
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Ui_t1016", t1016)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.control_bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Next", t1016)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.control_bt)

        
class Ui_t162(object):
    def setupUi(self, t162):
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(t162)
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Ui_t162", t162)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.control_bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Next", t162)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.control_bt)

        
class Ui_t168(object):
    def setupUi(self, t168):
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(t168)
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Ui_t168", t168)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.control_bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Next", t168)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.control_bt)

        
class Ui_t1610(object):
    def setupUi(self, t1610):
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(t1610)
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Ui_t1610", t1610)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.control_bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Next", t1610)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.control_bt)
        

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tasks = [
            't28', 't210', 't216', 
            't82', 't810', 't816', 
            't102', 't108', 't1016', 
            't162', 't128', 't1610'
        ]        
        self.uis = [
            Ui_t28(), Ui_t210(), Ui_t216(), 
            Ui_t82(), Ui_t810(), Ui_t816(), 
            Ui_t102(), Ui_t108(), Ui_t1016(), 
            Ui_t162(), Ui_t168(), Ui_t1610()
        ]
        
        self.pushButton_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("pushButton_13", self)
        self.pushButton_13.clicked.connect(self.bPall)

    def bPnextTask(self, _task):
        while 1:
            task = random.randint(0, 11)
            if task != _task: break
        self.tasks[task] = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget = self.tasks[task]               
        widget.setWindowTitle(str(task)*10)
        widget.resize(300, 200)
        ui = self.uis[task]                    
        ui.setupUi(widget)
        widget.move(0+(50*task), 0+(35*task))
        widget.show()
        ui.control_bt.clicked.connect(lambda ch, _task=task: self.bPnextTask(_task))
        
    def bPall(self):
        task = random.randint(0, 11)
        self.tasks[task] = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget = self.tasks[task]             
        widget.setWindowTitle(str(task)*10)
        widget.resize(300, 200)
        ui = self.uis[task]                  
        ui.setupUi(widget)
        widget.move(0+(50*task), 0+(35*task))
        widget.show()
        ui.control_bt.clicked.connect(lambda ch, _task=task: self.bPnextTask(_task))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        for w in self.tasks:
            if isinstance(w, QtWidgets.QWidget):
                w.close()
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.setGeometry(900, 200, 150, 100)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хорошо, в будущих вопросах учту ваши советы, спасибо за ответ))